# How to set only Time for ui:inputDateTime tag at first time in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I want to default time to **9:00 AM** when user selects date first time. Still He is allowed to change the time.
I am using below tag for DateTime input field:

`<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="startDate" value="{!v.startDate}" label="Approved Event Start Date" class="form-control" displayDatePicker="true" required="true"/>`

[image: Default Time value:]

Comment: While not a great solution, you can perhaps use the code here for the ui:inputDateTime: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/datetime-picker which splits apart everything, this way you can set the default of each component seperately

Comment: If you don't specify a perfectly valid ISO 8601 Date/Time, you get undefined behavior. You can specify a date without a time, but not a time without a date. You might want to see if you can report this as a bug.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have tried to set only Time It doesn't work. So I am trying to use change event attribute on the Input tag => change="{!c.setApprovalStartTime}" 
But I am not able to restrict it to run only once. It would be great if you could help me here. Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit Change handlers run on every change, yes. You'd have to make your own custom input if you want behavior at this level of detail.

Comment: @sfdcfox   I figured it out with below approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted the below approach.
Create ui:inputDateTime with Change Event see below:

```
<aura:attribute name="startDate" type="DateTime" />
<ui:inputDateTime aura:id="startDate" value="{!v.startDate}" label="Start Date" class="form-control" displayDatePicker="true" change="{!c.setStartTime}" required="true"/>
```

Create below Java Script code and store it in Static Resource..

```
(function(w){
var utilityMethods = {
    "setStartTime":setStartTime,

};
function setStartTime(){
    myUtil.setStartTime = function(){};
    return 'Affirmative';
}
w.myUtil = utilityMethods;  })(window);
```

Now use above static Resource in your Lightning Component and 
 inside your **controller.JS** create below function:

```
setStartTime: function(component, event, helper){

    var startdateValue = new Date(component.get("v.startDate"));
    var responseFromStaticResource = myUtil.setTimeSS();
    if(responseFromStaticResource){
        alert('It will run only once as Required');
         startdateValue.setHours(9);
         startdateValue.setMinutes(0);
        component.set("v.startDate", startdateValue.toISOString());
    }

}
```

**You are done! It works perfect. Select the date at the first time the Time value will be set to 9:00 AM**